# Merge two APFS containers

Tags: hard-drive, apfs

I want to know if I can merge two APFS containers.

[image]

I want to merge `Untitled` to `mac, mac-Data` container. 
If I click `-` button at the bottom, `Untitled` container is merged to `Workspace`. But this is not what I want to do.

Anyone can help ?

This image is `diskutil list` result.

[image]

I am using Mac Mojave now.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the output from the Terminal application command `diskutil list`?

Comment: Yeah - it's not clear at all what three items you actually have. If my start to an answer doesn't help - let's dig into the exact file allocations and see if we can get you to where you want to be storage wise...

Comment: I've edited my question. So you can see 3 containers - disk1, 3, 4. Disk 1 is System volume and Disk4 is empty one. I want to merge Disk4 to Disk1.

Comment: Merging won't work! Create a new HFS+ volume/partition on disk2 (which seems to be empty) (= disk2s2) > backup mac to it (just to be sure) & copy content of workspace to the same volume as separate folder > remove disk0s3 and disk0s4 > fully expand disk0s2 > create a new apfs volume (workspace) in disk0s2 > copy workspace content on disk2s2 back to the new volume. **But**: assuming this is a Catalina system your mac volume seems to be irregular/hosed because it's way too large for a standard installation (and mac - data is too small)...

Comment: I am not using Catalina. Just mojave yet.

Comment: @O.o The volume scheme of disk0s2/disk1 is typical for Catalina - did you try to upgrade to Catalina? Or is it in progress?

Comment: Never. In the past, I've upgraded to Catalina, but the Graphics became 7MB and I couldn't find good driver for Catalina. So I reinstalled Mojave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - there is no merging. The point of APFS is to put all your volumes in one container and not make multiple containers, but you're where you are today.

Looking at the image you should have more than enough space to move what you can off of the middle container (into the first ideally or into the last if needed. Then you can remove the middle empty container, grow the first container, then complete cleanup

Of course, just copying the data from the second two containers to another drive and then removing both, growing the first is the simplest way to return to one container with all your space.

David's comment to show the diskutil list will unlock someone giving you the exact commands needed to accomplish the rough sketch idea I've put in words here.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that I have a current and complete backup (and, knowing me, two separate backups) of all the data from the partitions.

Then I would erase / remove all 3 partitions and start fresh from scratch.

I have had issues combining partitions in the past and clearly, based on posts here, so have others.

Starting fresh from scratch gives me the least worry solution.

Comment: If I remove all 3 partitions, where do you backup your data? Do I need another hdd?

Comment: @O.o separate means completely separate devices : another disk or other storage medium.